# Constant (or macro) definition for a BIND9 zone database

Tags: dns, macros, bind

I am using BIND9 on a Linux system. In my zone db files I have multiple occurrences for the same IP in multiple `IN A` entries. For example, my `www`, `mail`, `ns`, etc., `IN A` entries refer to the same IP addresses. I do not want and I cannot use `IN CNAME` entries for this.

For example, part of my DNS zone db file might be something like this:

```
...
ns1  IN A    _ip1_
     IN AAAA _ip2_
ns2  IN A    _ip3_
     IN AAAA _ip4_
...
wwwa IN A    _ip1_
     IN AAAA _ip2_
...
wwwb IN A    _ip3_
     IN AAAA _ip4_
...
mail IN A    _ip1_
     IN AAAA _ip2_
     IN A    _ip3_
     IN AAAA _ip4_
...
ntp  IN A    _ip1_
     IN AAAA _ip2_
     IN A    _ip3_
     IN AAAA _ip4_
...
```

In the above example, on each place where I have to enter `_ip1_` for example, I have to enter the a *same IP address*. This is prone to errors.

How can I define a "macro" or a "constant" and use it later in a BIND9 db file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define variables or constants in a Bind9 zone file. Bind9 only supports `$ORIGIN`, `$TTL`, `$GENERATE` and `$INCLUDE` as "programmatic" entries, neither of which do what you need.

It would be fairly trivial to use a template-like system. You could use a bash script with a `heredoc`, or use the `envsubst` utility:

1. Create a "template" zone file:

```
ns1  IN A    $ip1
     IN AAAA $ip2
ns2  IN A    $ip3
     IN AAAA $ip4
...
wwwa IN A    $ip1
     IN AAAA $ip2
```

2. Write a small shell script that sets the variables and does the expansion, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip1='198.51.100.42'
ip2='2001:db8:1234:100::42'
ip3='198.51.100.17'
ip4='2001:db8:1234:100::17'

envsubst < template_file > real_zone_file.zone
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, that is something that I already considered. There are also many "macro languages" that will help me dynamically create bind zone files. However, my zone files are also updated by other forces, for example, scripts called by Let's Encrypt Certbot. So, I need to have one single original zone file that is manually and programmatically updated.